# JBoss7 + seam2.3 = java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method

Tags: jboss, seam, jboss7.x, seam2

We are trying to migrate seam2.2 + jboss4.2.3 to jboss7.1.1 + seam2.3 and we are currently facing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: 
when resolving overridden method 
"org.jboss.seam.faces.DateConverter.getAsString
(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;
Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;" 
the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) 
of the current class, org/jboss/seam/faces/DateConverter,
and its superclass loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader), 
have different Class objects for the type ext/FacesContext;
Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;
Ljava/lang/Object;)
Ljava/lang/String; 
used in the signature
```

Base on the articles I've found on google it seems like we are loading 2x the jboss-seam jar. 1 from the app and 1 from JBoss, but I'm not 100% sure though.

Any idea what's causing the problem?

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 1):

Some jars are needed to build your application, but shouldn't be deployed with it.
Check the deployed-jars.list in your Seam app and make sure you're not deploying jars already loaded by jboss.

It won't be a Seam jars, those are not included with the jboss loader unless you add them.  It will probably be a JSF jar.